# iOS ScrollView + Page Controller inside Navigation Controller: How to change title of the Navigation Bar for each page?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, uipagecontrol

In my app I have a UINavigationController. One of the views in the NavigationController has a ScrollView + Page Control combo. There are 3 pages in the scroll view. Is there any way to change the title of the NavigationBar according to the scroll view page on which you currently are?

I tried these two methods found in other posts:

self.navigationItem.titleView

and

viewController.title = @"title text";

but they didn't work. And on top of all I'm not even sure where in the code I should change the title. In the change page function ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just found on another post that you can create a label and customize it as you wish and then assign it to self.navigationItem.titleView instead of trying to set constant @"TITLE" to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing self.title = @"title". I put the code in the method which takes care of scrolling around the pages.